# AngularFIRE Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'AngularFireList<{}>'

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-cli, angularfire2

I'm following [**this tutorial**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqWXRX5fxGQ) about how to connect angular with firebase database. But in minute 17:30 I'm getting this error:

**Property 'subscribe' does not exist  on type 'AngularFireList<{}>'**

my AppComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireDatabaseModule} from 'angularfire2/database';

import {AngularFireAuth, AngularFireAuthModule} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Country } from './models/country';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  countries: any[];

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase )
  {
     db.list('/Country/countries')
     .subscribe(countries => { //  <--ERROR IS HERE
      this.countries = countries;
      console.log(this.countries);
      });
  }
}
```

My model:

```
export class Country {
     // --ATTRIB--
     id: string;
     name: string;
     code: string;
     urlFlag: string;
}
```

Cant find anything about this error. I'm beginner in angular. Thanks if can help me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Starting in AngularFire 5.0 you'll want to use one of `snapshotChanges()`, `valueChanges<T>()`, `stateChanges()`, or `auditTrail()`. [See the 5.0 migration guide](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md).

Get started with the most basic, `valueChanges()`:

```
export class AppComponent {
  countries: Observable<Country[]>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase ) {
    this.countries = db.list('/Country/countries').valueChanges();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

A simpler change would to be add  `valueChanges()` before `.subscribe()`

```
db.list('/Country/countries').valueChanges().subscribe(countries => {
    this.countries = countries;
    console.log(this.countries);
});
```

Comment: i really don't get it why google keeps updating this in such a manner, it toke me so long to do such a simple task ( so lame).

Answer (score 2):

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(db : AngularFireDatabase){
 db.list('/courses').valueChanges().subscribe()
  }
}
```

In Angular firebase version 5.0 and above **.subscribe** is available after **.valuechanges()**

Answer (score 1):

```
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Import code the code,

```
 countries: Observable<any[]>;
 allCountries: any;

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase ) {
    this.countries = db.list('/yourpath').valueChanges();  
    this.countries.subscribe(countries => {
      this.allCountries = countries;
      console.log(this.allCountries);
    })
    console.log(this.countries)
  }
```

Comment: May be you can add a bit of an explanation why your example answers the question and how it differs from other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the next:

```
export class AppComponent {
  countries: any[];

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase )
  {
      this.countries = db.list('/Country/countries').valuesChanges();
  }
}
```

And if you have a model then:

```
export class AppComponent {
  countries: Country[];

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase )
  {
     this.countries = db.list<Country>('/Country/countries').valueChanges();
  }
}
```