# Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'AngularFireList<{}>'

Tags: firebase, ionic3, angularfire2

I'm trying to run a chat app using ionic and I'm getting this message

```
[19:55:51]  typescript: src/pages/chat/chat.ts, line: 26 
        Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'AngularFireList<{}>'. 

  L25:  this.username = this.navParams.get('username');
  L26:  this._chatSubscription = this.db.list('/chat').subscribe( data => {
  L27:    this.messages = data;

[19:55:51]  typescript: src/pages/chat/chat.ts, line: 37 
        Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'PromiseLike<void>'. 

  L36:    // message is sent
  L37:  }).catch( () => {
  L38:    // some error. maybe firebase is unreachable
```

can anybody help me?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46734663/4654957

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify valueChanges() or snapshotChanges() before you subscribe.

> **valueChanges()** Returns an Observable of data as a synchronized array of JSON objects. All Snapshot metadata is stripped and just the method provides only the data.
>
> **snapshotChanges()** Returns an Observable of data as a synchronized
>   array of AngularFireAction[].

You can read more about retrieving data [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md)

So your code should look like this:

```
this.db.list('chat').valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
  this.messages = data;
});
```